# Ошибка php в шаблоне tpl

Tags: php

У меня есть одно приложение где используются шаблоны... Есть шаблон links.tpl, вот начало этого файла:

```
// Fetch all links
$query = $database->getLinks($session->uid);
if(!empty($query)){
  $result = mysqli_num_rows($query); //Вот тут возникает ошибка
  if (($result > 0)){
    $links = array();
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $links[] = $data;
    }
  }
```

Я не смог найти в шаблоне подключение к БД... И получаю такую ошибку:

**PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/Templates/links.tpl on line 15, referer: http://travianx5.ru/karte.php
[Tue Jan 28 10:07:39.522796 2014] [:error] [pid 29295] [client 192.168.1.1:65524]**

Какую еще проверку посоветуете добавить к **!empty**?

```
function getLinks($id){
        $link =  mysqli_connect(SQL_SERVER, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, SQL_DB) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        $q = 'SELECT * FROM `' . TB_PREFIX . 'links` WHERE `userid` = ' . $id . ' ORDER BY `pos` ASC';
        return mysqli_query($link, $q) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    }
```

Comment: проверяйте что в `$query`: `var_dump($query);`

Comment: echo $query вернуло 1, а var_dump($query) вернул bool(true)

Comment: Убрал or die mysqli_error($link) и теперь ошибка - Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/Templates/links.tpl on line 14

Comment: Ну так приведите нам что в этой 14 строке накодировано

Comment: Вот что выдает var_dump($query): **object(mysqli_result)#18 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }**

Comment: это нормальный вывод, вызывайте fetch_assoc(), она заполнит поля значениями, если они есть конечно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменил ответ, так как нашел серьезную ошибку в коде:

```
return mysqli_query($link, $q) or die(mysqli_error($link)); // неправильно либо TRUE либо die()
```

ПХП интерпретирует эту or в return как булево выражение (у return самый низкий приоритет из операторов), поэтому вместо того, что бы вернуть идентификатор результата при успешном выполнении, он возвращает результат булева выражения something1 OR something2, где первое something == true. (http://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php смотрите в комментах эту проблему)

```
return $res = mysqli_query($link, $q) or die(mysqli_error($link)); // правильно либо $res либо die()
```

ПЫСЫ: А вообще в ООП лучше использовать механизм исключений, а не эти "допотопные" методы обработки ошибок.

Comment: **echo $query** вернуло **1**,
а **var_dump($query)** вернул **bool(true)**

Comment: Убрал or die mysqli_error($link) и теперь ошибка - Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/Templates/links.tpl on line 14

Comment: Вот что выдает var_dump($query): **object(mysqli_result)#18 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }**

Answer (score 2):

Что возвращает у вас $query гляньте:

```
$query = $database->getLinks($session->uid);
echo $query;
return;
if(!empty($query)){
  $result = mysqli_num_rows($query); //Вот тут возникает ошибка
  if (($result > 0)){
    $links = array();
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $links[] = $data;
    }
  }
```

да и getLinks никогда не вернёт null так как есть die(mysqli_error($link))

Comment: echo $query вернуло 1
а var_dump($query) вернул bool(true)

Comment: Убрал or die mysqli_error($link) и теперь ошибка - Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in /var/www/Templates/links.tpl on line 14

Comment: Вот что выдает var_dump($query): **object(mysqli_result)#18 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }**

Comment: Тут разбирать результирующий объект, тоесть if(!empty($query)) должно выглядить както так:

   if($query["lengths"]!=NULL)